# Access restrictions (modularity) of artifacts in Maven

Tags: java, maven, java-8, java-package

I know that starting with Java 9 (we're still on 8), it is possible to restrict access to packages for other modules, if you stick to the Java module system. We are doing Java EE and I don't know if anyone is using the module system here -- it is unlikely we ever will.

I wondered whether Maven could offer a similar service. One could add a file to an artifact stating which external accesses are allowed (in the sense: this groupId or this GAV may access this package). Then a Maven build that uses this artifact as dependency could check whether these rules are fulfilled.

Are there any Maven plugins available in this direction?

We are building large and complicated ear files (and this will not substantially change in the near future) and have problems controlling the various ways in which jars of different development teams are used.